# Плагин WordPress для перехода к меткам на карте

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, плагин, карты, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, как организовать работу карты следующим образом:

- на карте поставлены метки (несколько объектов по всей России);
- при клике на наименование объекта над картой на карте отображается метка с этим местом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал несколько карт через Yandex Конструктор карт, и написал onclick смену стилей (display: block / display:none).

Answer (score 0):

Есть плагин GEO my WP, вот демо: http://demo.geomywp.com/search-post-type-with-categories/